# Set a default input value that can be editable

Tags: jsf

I would like to create a JSF application 
Where a user must provide their age. This will default to 18 and be editable (If the user wants to provide a different value).

How to achieve this functionality?

The input value provided by the user or the default value ie which is 18 would be saved in the Database

```
<h:form>
    <p:panel id="panel" header="New User">

    <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">

        <p:outputLabel for="age" value="Age:" />
        <p:inputText id="age" value="#{managedBean.entityBean.age}" required="true" label="Age">
        </p:inputText>

    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton value="Save" update="panel" action="#{managedBean.save}"  />
</p:panel>
</h:form>
```

Entity.java

```
public class Entity implements Serializable {
@Column(name = "AGE")
private Integer age;

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}
```

managedBean.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "managedBeanJava")
@ViewScoped
public class managedBeanJava implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(managedBeanJava.class);

    private Entity entityBean;

    public Entity getEntityBean() {
        return entityBean;
    }

    public void setEntityBean(Entity entityBean) {
        this.entityBean = entityBean;
    }

    private Integer age  = 50;

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        Map<String, String> params = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();

    }

public void save(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    try {

        entityBean.setAge(this.entityBean.getAge());

    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have two `age` properties? Why are you setting the one of the `managedBean` while your input component is showing the one from `entityBean`? Try to think logically.

Comment: @BalusC   Thanks, setting it in the entity resolved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define default value of `<h:inputText>` in your managed bean directly.

`private Integer age = 18;`

Comment: Tried this but it did not set the default value to 18, nothing is shown up in the UI

Comment: Are you sure the `getAge()` is called ? Can I see full definition of your managedBean ?

Comment: @ManagedBean(name = "managedBeanJava")
@ViewScoped
public class managedBeanJava implements Serializable {

Comment: private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(managedBeanJava.class);

Comment: private Integer age  = 50;

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

Comment: @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        Map<String, String> params = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap();

    }

Comment: Your bean name is not `managedBean` but `managedBeanJava` and you link EL to `managedBean.entityBean.age` instead of age property from managedBean....